# How is value returned by lambda using a static local wrong in MSVC2017 15.9.3 with /std:c++17?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, c++17, compiler-bug

The example code below prints values from a lambda function, which simply increments and returns the value of a static local counter variable.

It prints `0,1` and `2,3` as expected with gcc and clang with C++17. But not in Visual Studio Community 2017 15.9.3 with `/std:c++17` set - it prints `0,0` and `2,3` instead.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    auto f = [] {
        static int i = 0;
        return i++;
    };
    const int v1 = f(); // Expect v1 = 0
    const int v2 = f(); // Expect v2 = 1

    // Prints the wrong values (MSVC 15.9.3 with /std:c++17)
    std::cout << v1 << "," << v2 << std::endl; // Expect "0,1", prints "0,0"

    // Prints the right values (or ought to with C++17 sequencing, anyway)
    std::cout << f() << "," << f() << std::endl; // Expect "2,3", prints "2,3"

    return 0;
}
```

The strange output (in x86 debug builds)

```
0,0
2,3
```

It looks like a compiler bug (so we filed the report): https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/347419/unexpected-return-from-lambda-with-static-local-va.html

In what way is the produced program wrong, such that it incorrectly prints `0` for both `v1` and `v2`, but correctly prints `2, 3` after that? Any educated guess at what the compiler bug is?

As a workaround I used a capture instead:

```
auto f = [i = 0]() mutable {
    return i++;
};
```

UPDATE - as a side note, the output from the example above is different again in x86 release builds:

```
0,1
3,2
```

There is another existing issue with MSVC, where `std::cout`'s `<<` operator is not sequenced left-to-right despite `/std:c++17` being set, which I would speculate results in `3,2` being output here, at least.

Comment: You really think that we can explain the internal workings of a closed source compiler?

Comment: Wouldn't your workaround be better if you would enter the function twice?

Comment: What is really weird is if you put a breakpoint on the first `cout` line the auto watch window shows `v1` and `v2` being `0` and `1` respectively.

Comment: All looking at the assembly tells us is that yes, it does the wrong thing.

Comment: @aschepler Good point, I rephrased the question a little.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MSVC compiles the following cleanly:

```
constexpr int foo() {
    static int i = 0;
    return i++;
}
static_assert(foo() == foo()); // oh no
```

That is *not* standards compliant.

So, what happens is that since C++17, lambdas are implicitly `constexpr` if they can be. MSVC wrongly decides that the lambda is `constexpr`, and so folds `f()` into a constant for `v2` (that it got from `v1`). It doesn't do this when you directly output it because it apparently doesn't eagerly evaluate `constexpr` stuff like gcc does (or uses some other heuristic that we can't know about).

Comment: Thanks. I had noticed that removing ``const`` from ``v1`` and ``v2`` made the issue vanish, which would figure if doing that makes the compiler decide not to fold the lambda.

Comment: @SamTwidale Jup, they're not folded because they're not `const` (nor `constexpr`).

Comment: I just noticed something else, perhaps this is my bug or is it MSVC again? In x86 release builds, the example outputs ``0,1`` and ``3,2`` on my PC, although I thought that std::cout's << operator was sequenced in C++17 though. Could that be contributing to this bug? If I change the ``cout``s to print ``v1`` and ``v2`` and the two calls to ``f`` with separate calls, it correctly outputs ``0,1`` and ``2,3``.

Comment: @SamTwidale Even if `v1` and `v2` are `const`?. But yes, that's a known bug for MSVC.

Comment: Yes, in x86 release, it outputs ``0,1`` and ``3,2`` even if ``v1`` and ``v2`` are declared const. I should have tried that earlier. Could the resulting behaviour be a combination of both bugs?

Comment: @SamTwidale Don't think so. Probably has to do with the constant folding again.